# prolog f(X) :- X==[]

Tags: prolog

when I have the prolog programm

```
f(X) :- X==[].
```

the output is

```
|:-f(X).
false.
:-f([]).
true.
```

in the first output prolog claims that there is no `X`, so that `f(X)` is true.

But `f([])` is true, so prolog should have said `X=[]`. as the answer to the first query.

Why is this? How can I fix it.

```
a(X,X).
b(A,B) :- A==X,B==X.
```

has an even worse problem:

```
|:-a([a],[a]).
true.
:-b([a],[a]).
false.
```

I would believe that `a` and `b` are the exact same statements, just written differently.

The IDE claims that `A==X` is always false, so I guess I have a severe misunderstanding about how variables work in prolog.

Comment: `(==)/2` is not a pure relation. It is rather test *at a current point in time**. Use `(=)/2` instead to get what you probably expect. Thus `b(A,B) :- A=X, B=X.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==/2` does not do what you think it does. To quote the documentation, `@Term1 == @Term2` is

> True if `Term1` is equivalent to `Term2`. A variable is only identical to a sharing variable.

That means that `A == A` is true, but `A == B` is false, and `A == []` is false.

What you are looking for is *unification*, `=/2`, where

- `A = A` is true
- `A = B` is true (and `A` and `B` become the same variable: `A = B, A = 3` results in both `A` and `B` becoming 3).
- `A = []` is true (and `A` is unified with the empty list).

See

- `=/2`
  [SWI-Prolog Manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2)
- `==/2`
  [SWI-Prolog Manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D%3D/2)